# Can I say, "with who"?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

Can we say,

> 1. "He is a guide **with who** we went on a tour of the island."

I was told to write,

> 2. "He is a guide **with whom** we went on a tour of the island."

Why is only "with whom" acceptable here?

Comment: A [related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/with-who-vs-with-whom) at ELU. And another one: "[What's the rule for using Whom and Who correctly?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly)"

Comment: It depends. :) . . . In your example, you most probably ought to use *"with whom"*. But there are situations where *"With who"* are acceptable (or perhaps even preferred), such as in responses, e.g. *A: "I went to the movies last night with your boyfriend." B: "With who?"*

Comment: @F.E. Good example! I just added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

### You can't say *with who,* not even casually

The word **whom** is dying out of English, but it's not dead yet. It remains in use in formal speech. In informal speech, people people usually replace it with **who** except when this sounds especially awkward. Many people aren't sure when to say **who** and when to say **whom**, but they recognize some familiar phrases that use **whom**. Since they're not sure which word to use, they restructure the sentence to avoid having to making the choice. One of those phrases is **with whom**. These are the same phrases where replacing **whom** with **who** sounds especially awkward even in informal speech.

### When to say *whom*

The correct way to use **whom** is as a relative pronoun introducing a clause where it stands for the object of the verb, which must be a person. The relevant verb is the one *inside* the relative clause, not the main verb of the surrounding sentence. For example:

> We went on a tour of the island with this guide.

**This guide** is the object of **with**, so if you make that into a relative clause in a larger sentence, it calls for **whom**:

> This is the guide with whom we went on a tour of the island.

However, in contemporary English, this sounds too formal for casual conversation. So, usually people reword it to avoid using any relative pronoun at all, by moving **with** to the end of the sentence:

> This is the guide we went on a tour of the island with.

### When to say *who*

**Who** does the same thing as **whom**, except it serves as the subject of the verb in the relative clause that it introduces. For example:

> This guide took us on a tour of the island.

Here, **this guide** is the subject of the sentence. So, if you make it into a relative clause, you refer to the guide with **who**:

> The is the guide who took us on a tour of the island.

### As interrogative pronouns

The same applies when **who** and **whom** are used as interrogative pronouns:

> With whom did you go on a tour of the island?
>
> Who took you on a tour of the island?

The first question sounds very formal, though, so normally people reword it like this:

> Who did you go on a tour of the island with?

This is a typical case where people replace **whom** with **who** even though, by the highest standards of formality, it's incorrect.

### When replacing *whom* with *who* sounds awkward and when it doesn't

Replacing **whom** with **who** sounds awkward when **whom** immediately follows a preposition, as in **with whom**. Certain stock phrases, like "to whom it may concern", are very familiar, and their echo in people's minds makes **who** sound wrong in very similar-sounding situations.

There can be no strict rule about this kind of thing, of course, but you can most often get away with saying **who** in place of **whom** when **who** is placed away from the preposition that governs it or when it's the direct object of a verb without a preposition. For example, "This is the guide who we went on a tour with." **Whom** is still correct in that sentence, but it would sound formal. In formal speech, **who** would technically be wrong, but many people wouldn't notice. Another situation where **who** can replace **whom** informally is in a question with the emphatic or surprised word order, where you repeat a declarative sentence that was just said but with one noun replaced by **who**; for example, "You kissed *who?*"

### A simple test

If the terminology of grammar confuses you but you have some intuition for when to say **he** and when to say **him**, you can tell whether **who** or **whom** is correct by restating the relative clause as a full sentence and replacing **who/whom** with **he** or **him**, whichever is appropriate. **He** corresponds to **who** and **him** corresponds to **whom**.

For example, no one would say:

> We went on a tour of the island with he.

Even people who don't have any feeling for when to say **whom** would say:

> We went on a tour of the island with him.

Comment: Not ever? Ever ever? Ever, ever, ever? How about "***you refer to the guide with who:***"?  (penultimate line of your section *When to say who* ... ) Sorry, couldn't help it ... ;)

Comment: @Araucaria Obviously, when the word **who** is quoted (referring to the word itself) rather than serving as a  pronoun, then it works just like any other noun.

Comment: Casually, "This is the tour who we went on the tour with," would be just fine.

Comment: @thumbtackthief There's an example like that in the answer. I just retitled the section to make that more obvious.

Comment: I reject wholeheartedly your thesis that saying *with who* is unnatural in casual or everyday  English. It may a regional thing.

Comment: @CarSmack Have you heard people saying things like "The person with who I had a conversation last night"? Where I live (USA), I've heard things like that very rarely—usually followed by snickering when the speaker leaves the room. I think the derisive laughter is the kind that usually attends a person trying to use big words and getting them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say "He is a guide with who we went on a tour of the island".
However, we can say in formal writing that "He is a guide with whom we went on a tour of the island".

In spoken/informal English, I think it's natural to say that "He is a guide who we went on a tour of the island with".

Comment: I would appreciate the comments of the user who has dwnvoted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can **say**:

A. "He is a guide with who we went on a tour of the island."

However,  99% of the time we would **say**:

B. "He is a guide who we went on a tour of the island with."

So I suggest using B in everyday spoken language. But I would think the following would be more common:

C. He is a guide that took us on a tour of the island.

Notice that in C., the relative pronoun *that* is used after a person. This is common, and I would say at least as common as using *who* after a person. I am talking about everyday speech.

In **writing**, we would most likely use *whom* in A and *who* in C. As for B, depending on context, we might use either *who* or *whom* in writing. In writing, when in doubt, use *whom.* An exception to this is when you are writing what someone says in a direct quote. In this case, use B or C.

As far as *with who* in general, I find the following uses all natural in everyday spoken English:

D. "You went on a tour *with who?*"

E. "*With who?*"

F. "*With who* did you go on a tour with?"

G. "You went to the movies *with **who***?!'

All these sound natural to me in everyday conversation. It is what I say. Using *whom* would be optional, but it would sound too formal and *unnatural.* Other native speakers may disagree. Obviously, another answer strongly disagrees, but I don't agree with it. :)